# uniq skip first N characters/fields

Tags: bash, file, printing, extract, uniq

This is the contents of logfile I have

```
    {"timestamp":"2016-04-20T12:24:35","event_type":"alert","src_ip":"198.55.103.12","src_port":44927,"dest_ip":"127.0.0.1","dest_port":9200,"honeypot":{"name":"Elasticpot","n$
{"timestamp":"2016-04-20T12:24:36","event_type":"alert","src_ip":"198.55.103.12","src_port":44927,"dest_ip":"127.0.0.1","dest_port":9200,"honeypot":{"name":"Elasticpot","n$
{"timestamp":"2016-04-20T12:24:37","event_type":"alert","src_ip":"198.55.103.12","src_port":44927,"dest_ip":"127.0.0.1","dest_port":9200,"honeypot":{"name":"Elasticpot","n$
{"timestamp":"2016-04-20T12:24:38","event_type":"alert","src_ip":"198.55.103.12","src_port":44927,"dest_ip":"127.0.0.1","dest_port":9200,"honeypot":{"name":"Elasticpot","n$
```

Using bash, I want to grep unique lines and put the result in a textfile. I want to skip the timestamp field when checking for uniqueness since as you can see, apart from the timestamp, those four lines are the same. This is what I have so far:

```
sudo grep "alert" /home/tsec/prototype/logs/elasticpot.log | uniq | tail -n 10 > /home/tsec/prototype/logs/extractedlogs/elasticpotresult.log
```

So the output in a csv file should be:

```
 {"timestamp":"2016-04-20T12:24:38","event_type":"alert","src_ip":"198.55.103.12","src_port":44927,"dest_ip":"127.0.0.1","dest_port":9200,"honeypot":{"name":"Elasticpot","n$
```

I have to use unique for sure with the -f flag but not sure how. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sort -u -t, -k2,8 elasticpot.log
```

- `-u` → for unique
- `-t,` → comma is the delimiter
- `-k2,8` → key fields are 2 to 8 (**Or** `-k2` → key fields are from 2 to end)

Test result:

```
{"timestamp":"2016-04-20T12:24:35","event_type":"alert","src_ip":"198.55.103.12","src_port":44927,"dest_ip":"127.0.0.1","dest_port":9200,"honeypot":{"name":"Elasticpot","n$
```